# Conditional Variable Assignment in Azure Devops Build Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Azure Pipelines has [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#functions) and [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops), but I can not find any way to assign one of two values from the parameter to a variable, based on a condition.

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

```
parameters:
- name: major
  displayName: " Major Version(Default 3)"
  type: string
  default: 3

- name: minor
  displayName: 'Minor Version(Default 15)'
  type: string
  default: 15
  values:
  - 15
  - 16
  - 17
  - 18
  - 19

- name: patch
  displayName: 'Patch Version(Default 0)'
  type: string
  default: 0

- name: checksum
  displayName: 'Pattern is minor version.patch version, checksum'
  type: string
  values:
  - '15.0, 8003fcfe34dc224be816921e9543fa58ba195653' 
  - '18.1, d8e42f7a7b85ad72ba27117d1f13a790228f1369'
  - '19.0, 4e66eeedba4e1f3ea26cadb0c2bfa96264e7c8fb'

variables:
  major: ${{ parameters.major }}
  minor: ${{ parameters.minor }}
  patch: ${{ parameters.patch }}
  finalChecksum : ${{ if contains(parameters.checksum, parameters.minor.parameters.patch) }}: parameters.checksum.split(',')[1]
```

what I'm after is `finalchecksum`:  (as validation works fine)

```
if parameter.checksum contains/startsWith minor.patch:
then 
  finalchecksum = parameters.checksum.split(',')[1]
```

so here,

if the minor and patch versions are 18.1 then finalchecksum = d8e42f7a7b85ad72ba27117d1f13a790228f1369

In my task, I have something like this :

```
- bash: |
              echo $(finalChecksum)
```

Then it prints below error:

```
Line 1: `echo True:15.0, 8003fcfe34dc224be816921e9543fa58ba195653.Split(",")[0]'
```

All I'm interested in printing the `checksum` and I even don't know `parameters.checksum.split(',')[1]` does exist in AzDo world. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in functions to replace your variable. I used [replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#replace) and [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#format) functions in my sample.
Here is my configuration:

```
parameters:
- name: major
  displayName: " Major Version(Default 3)"
  type: string
  default: 3

- name: minor
  displayName: 'Minor Version(Default 15)'
  type: string
  default: 15
  values:
  - 15
  - 16
  - 17
  - 18
  - 19

- name: patch
  displayName: 'Patch Version(Default 0)'
  type: string
  default: 0

- name: checksum
  displayName: 'Pattern is minor version.patch version, checksum'
  type: string
  values:
  - '15.0, 8003fcfe34dc224be816921e9543fa58ba195653' 
  - '18.1, d8e42f7a7b85ad72ba27117d1f13a790228f1369'
  - '19.0, 4e66eeedba4e1f3ea26cadb0c2bfa96264e7c8fb'

variables:
  major: ${{ parameters.major }}
  minor: ${{ parameters.minor }}
  patch: ${{ parameters.patch }}
  format: $[format('{0}.{1}, ', variables['minor'], variables['patch'])]
  ${{ if contains(parameters.checksum, parameters.minor.parameters.patch) }}:
    finalChecksum : $[replace('${{parameters.checksum}}',variables['format'],'')]
```

Result of echo $(finalChecksum):

[image]

In addition, I followed this document to [conditionally assign a variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-assign-a-variable).